# Error using Pyfhel

Tags: encryption

I am trying to use **Pyfhel** library to perform some operations on encrypted integer list. I am doing one multiplication operation and later performing an addition operation. But while performing addition operation, I randomly get following error:

`IndexError('Unable to find key in unordered_map.’,)`

If I try to decrypt that encrypted value on which I try to perform addition operation, I am getting the same error.
Can anyone please let me know what could be the problem?

Thanks!

(Couldn't add the related tags but it's around Homomorphic Encryption using Pyfhel library, Python implementation of HElib)

Comment: Where is the code...

Answer (score 1):

All I can tell you so far is that this error is originated by a search in the unordered map that contains all the cyphertexts. This unordered map is inside the Pyfhel object, accessed via a C++ call. As usual, it shouldn't be happenning. Right now, efforts are being put into upgrading Pyfhel so that you can hold each cyphertext in a single Python object, thus rendering your current error obsolete.

Comment: And this question is 100% obsolete now. Better use Github issues for things like this!